# How to stop text created by CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox from layering

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, datagridview

I have the following cell which is used for my custom column data type on my data grid.

```
public class DataGridViewReviewerCell : DataGridViewCell
{
    protected override object GetFormattedValue(object value, int rowIndex, ref DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
                                                TypeConverter valueTypeConverter,
                                                TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter,
                                                DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return Value;
    }

    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex,
                                  DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue,
                                  string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
                                  DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
                                  DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, "", "", errorText,
                 cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
        var parent = (DataGridViewReviewerColumn) OwningColumn;
        var columnValue = (ReviewerCheckBox) Value;

        CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(
            graphics,
            new Point(cellBounds.X + 4, cellBounds.Y + 4),
            new Rectangle(cellBounds.X + 2, cellBounds.Y + 4, cellBounds.Width, cellBounds.Height - (4 * 2)),
            "     " + columnValue.ReviewerEmployeeName,
            parent.InheritedStyle.Font, 
            TextFormatFlags.Left,
            false,
            (columnValue.IsChecked ? CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal : CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal));

    }
}
```

This class works as expected however every time Paint() gets called the text (currently `"     " + columnValue.ReviewerEmployeeName`) keeps getting layered creating very unreadable text. I can't seem to find anything that will fix this problem.

### Slow piece of code

Here is the piece of code that is running very slowly. When I put this in debug mode it seems to be running endlessly.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;
using System;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("STEP A", new ReviewerCheckBox());
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("STEP B", new ReviewerCheckBox());
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex == -1 || e.ColumnIndex != 1) return;

            var cell = (ReviewerCheckBox) dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
            cell.IsChecked = !cell.IsChecked;
            cell.ReviewerEmployeeName = (cell.IsChecked ? Environment.UserName : String.Empty);

            //MessageBox.Show("Testing");
        }
    }

    public class ReviewerCheckBox
    {
        public string ReviewerEmployeeName { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    }
}

    public class DataGridViewReviewerColumn : DataGridViewColumn
    {
        public DataGridViewReviewerColumn()
        {
            CellTemplate = new DataGridViewReviewerCell();
            ReadOnly = false;
            SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
            Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be checking the `paintParts` argument to determine which parts you should be drawing. For example if the background needs drawing, the  DataGridViewPaintParts.Backgound flag will be set.

```
if (paintParts.HasFlag(DataGridViewPaintParts.Background))
{
  using (SolidBrush cellBackground =
    new SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor))
  {
    graphics.FillRectangle(cellBackground, cellBounds);
  }    
}

if (paintParts.HasFlag(DataGridViewPaintParts.Border))
{
  PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, cellStyle,
    advancedBorderStyle);
}

// Paint you cell content here
```

Here is a slightly more complete example

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;

namespace HideMainWinForm
{
  class DataGridViewReviewerCell : DataGridViewCell
  {
    protected override object GetFormattedValue(object value, int rowIndex, ref DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter valueTypeConverter, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
      return value;
    }

    protected override void Paint(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds, System.Drawing.Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
      if (paintParts.HasFlag(DataGridViewPaintParts.Background))
      {
        using (SolidBrush cellBackground =
          new SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor))
        {
          graphics.FillRectangle(cellBackground, cellBounds);
        }
      }

      if (paintParts.HasFlag(DataGridViewPaintParts.Border))
      {
        PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, cellStyle,
          advancedBorderStyle);
      }

      if (value != null)
      {
        CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(
          graphics,
          new Point(cellBounds.X + 4, cellBounds.Y + 4),
          new Rectangle(cellBounds.X+24,cellBounds.Y+4, cellBounds.Width-24, cellBounds.Height-4),
          formattedValue.ToString(),
          OwningColumn.InheritedStyle.Font,
          TextFormatFlags.Left,
          false,
          CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The two `HasFlag` function calls can be translated to

```
if ((paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.Background) == 
    DataGridViewPaintParts.Background)
{
  ...
}

if ((paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.Border) == 
    DataGridViewPaintParts.Border)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Chris. My `paintParts` arguments appears to be null. Also, `paintParts` doesn't have a `HasFlag` method.

Comment: @Mike, HasFlag is a member of the `enum` since framework 3.5. paintParts cannot be null since it is a Value Type (enum) which is not nullable.

Comment: Since I'm using VS2010 I switched to 4.0 and the error disappeared. I'll figure out how to change it to be compatible for 3.5. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Mike, the MSDN incorrectly documents Enum as having a HasFlag method in Framework 3.5. I have added the alternate flag check that you can use for Framework versions prior to Framework 4.0.

Comment: Any ideas as to why using this exact code would cause `Paint()` to get called in an infinite loop?

Comment: @Mike, I tested the code and the paint was not being called in an infinite loop. Can you share the code you are using, maybe I can see something that might cause this. How are you checking the infinite loop? If you break into the debugger the paint will run again if the grid cells where obscured by Visual Studio.

Comment: I was checking for the infinite loop by keeping my finger on the `F10` key for several minutes. I know it may not be infinite but I definitely counted more than it running 50+ times. I updated my question to include all of the code present in my project. Odd thing is that if you comment out the `MessageBox` inside of the `dataGridView1_CellClick` event function you'll notice the checking of the box happen instantly. I know that doesn't make much sense but I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: @Mike, if you are using F10, then I assume every step VS will obscure your Grid on the running form which will cause the region of the grid to be invalidated and a new Paint message to be sent to the grid. I would suggest that you use System.Diagnostics.WriteLine to write a message to the debug console when the paint occurs, this way you will not have the debugger infuencing the Windows repaint logic, at least not for your running application.

Comment: You're the man! I found out that `Paint()` does not get called in my `dataGridView1_CellClick` function. What I did to fix the problem was add `Refresh()` at the end of the event which would cause `Paint()` to run. `WriteLine` works great, by the way. Thanks for the help. MUCH appreciated. I'm curious to see how you got your code example to work. If you don't mind, could you please post all of your code?